# numpy.all has where parameter for what purpose

Tags: python, numpy

There is this `where` parameter in  `np.all` and I am not sure what it is for?

The documentation did not help much [here](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.all.html).

Any nice explanation somewhere? or can anyone explain it?

Answer (score 3):

From the documentation:

> where array_like of bool, optional Elements to include in checking for
> all True values. See reduce for details.

It basically tells which elements to consider for the application of the function. For example:

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.arange(5)
print(np.all(arr % 2 == 0))
print(np.all(arr % 2 == 0, where=[False, False, True, False, False]))
```

**Output**

```
False
True
```

In this expression:

```
np.all(arr % 2 == 0, where=[False, False, True, False, False])
```

Only the element at index 2 (that coincidentally is also 2) is considered. If you change to:

```
np.all(arr % 2 == 0, where=[False, False, True, True, False])
# False
```

the output is False because it will use the elements at index 2 and 3 (2 and 3 respectively).

Additional information and examples are found in the documentation of [`reduce`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.reduce.html#numpy.ufunc.reduce), quote (emphasis mine):

> **where** array_like of bool, optional A boolean array which is
> broadcasted to match the dimensions of array, and selects elements to
> include in the reduction. Note that for ufuncs like minimum that do
> not have an identity defined, one has to pass in also initial.